# What project is a good SILC substitute?

Tags: network, protocols, instant-messaging

As time has marched on, it would appear that the [Secure Internet Live Conferencing (SILC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_%28protocol%29) client/toolkit have lost a bit of steam, I can't find any current mailing lists, their website doesn't seem to get many updates - and the latest client source code has a timestamp from 2009.

I kinda get the feeling it's dead - if thats the case, are there any existing projects that fill the niche that SILC did?

What are all the cool kids using these days?

My wish list would be:

- Not a plugin for an IM client, they never seem to work very well.
- Cross platform (Linux, Windows, OSX)
- Curses client would be great, but.. if it's an anachronism at this point I won't try to fight it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably not very cool and don't use any of those currently but how about [jabber / XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)?

[This thread from 2009](http://www.mail-archive.com/jabberd2@lists.xiaoka.com/msg01255.html) seems to cover some of the differences and features with a healthy focus on security.

Comment: I hadn't even considered XMPP, +1 to you. I'll keep the question open for a couple days just in case someone else has some good feedback but.. I gotta take a look at XMPP..

Comment: You could combine XMPP with ORT (off the record) messaging, to achieve secrecy, if this is what you are after. You never say what "niche" SILC fills, so it is hard to know what features you are looking for.